# How do I implement multi thread on an Android Activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I've created a nested class within my Activity

```
public class MissionsActivity extends Activity {

class UpdateMissions implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        [...]
}

   [...]
}
```

In the thread I have to read a file and update some `TextFields` in the layout. I've tried implementing the `run()` method with a `while(true)` that reads and updates the fields, but the app just crashes when I start that `Activity`.

UPDATE: I've called the `execute()` method inside the `onCreate()` method of the UI Activity. The Task is only working the first time I enter the Activity, if i change and go back it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hey a solution could be trying to use Java's Executor Framework. Put the following code in your Activity.

With executors, you can use a `cachedThreadPool()` `singleThreadExecutor()` `fixedThreadPoolExecutor(int numOfThreads)` etc.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your task here.
        }
    });
```

Please note there are numerous Threading Models and techniques in Android, some Android Specific, some based in Android.

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[HandlerThread](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/handlerthreads-and-why-you-should-be-using-them-in-your-android-apps-dc8bf1540341)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AsyncTask. It allows you to load the file and show the progress on ui thread until the load it's finished.

Here you have a good example [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

I would recommend using RxJava or Live Data if you are more advance in developing but also the first solution is fine enough for beginning
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html